# iOS multithreading with Parse and dispatch_async

Tags: ios, multithreading, parse-platform

So I'm trying to load a list of usernames from Parse using a PFRelation query. The idea is for this list to be loaded and then used in the view controller that calls it. (through self.yourFriendArray). The original problem is that when I call this function in the viewDidLoad method of the view controller, the self.yourFriendArray array is nil because the query runs synchronously and does not update it.

So my plan was to use the main thread within this `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` call, but I'm not getting the desired output yet.

Am I multi-threading incorrectly?

Also, I'm just getting used to asking questions on stack overflow -- if there's something wrong with how I'm asking this one please suggest some updates in the comments! Thank you guys!

```
[[friendsRelation query] findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    for (PFUser *user in objects) {
        NSString *username = user.username;

        [tempArray addObject:username];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.yourFriendArray addObject:username];
        });
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm understanding well what you are trying to do... Is it that you have a tableView that loads the list of userNames from the yourFriendArray? Then, the only thing you need to do is to reload the tableView when the updated array is ready.

```
[[friendsRelation query] findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    for (PFUser *user in objects) {

        NSString *username = user.username;

        [self.yourFriendArray addObject:username];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

Sorry if this is not what you are asking...

Comment: Thanks for answering! So, yea I am trying to load data onto a tableView, sort of like SnapChat. I tried this and it's still not working. I think my problem is how Parse's findObjectsInBackground function runs asynchronously and how my view loads before the function is done running.

Comment: But `reloadData` should reload it after the objects have been fetched. @user3238594

Comment: I think that parse executes the query asynchronously but then executes the block in the main thread. So this should be all. How are you doing the query? Are you getting any objects?

Comment: What seems to be happening (according to the breakpoints I put) is that all the code runs in viewDidLoad and then the breakpoints start going off in my loadFriends function (where this block of code is). So it looks like my loadFriends function is running after all the view code has run. I've added the reloadData function but nothing's changed (still empty list).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[[friendsRelation query] findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        for (PFUser *user in objects) {
            NSString *username = user.username;

            [self.yourFriendArray addObject: username];
        }
        [self.tableview reloadData];
    });
}];
```